# How to move a picture to where a cursor clicked on the canvas

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I have an image of a character and I want to be able to move it to the position  of where my/the user's cursor is clicking on my canvas. for example-if the user clicked on the middle of the screen, I want his animal to walk there gradually, (at a certain speed). Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to move a picture to where a cursor clicked on the canvas

For your requirement, you could create [`DoubleAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation) for image. You could get your cursor clicked position with [`PointerPressed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed) event then pass the position X,Y value to `DoubleAnimation`  `ToProperty`. I created the sample you could refer.

**Code behind**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    RootCanvasLayout.PointerPressed += new PointerEventHandler(Pointer_Pressed);
}

private void Pointer_Pressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint currentPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(RootCanvasLayout);
    CreateAnimation(currentPoint);
}
void CreateAnimation(PointerPoint point)
{  var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation();
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimationY = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimationX.To = point.Position.X-Pic.ActualWidth/2;
    doubleAnimationX.Duration = duration;
    doubleAnimationY.To = point.Position.Y-Pic.ActualHeight/2;
    doubleAnimationY.Duration = duration;
    var conStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    conStoryboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimationX);
    conStoryboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimationY);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimationX, Pic);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimationY, Pic);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimationX, "(Canvas.Left)");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimationY, "(Canvas.Top)");
    conStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Canvas Name="RootCanvasLayout" Background="Ivory">
    <Image Name="Pic" Width="100" Height="100"
           Source="Assets/hello.png" 
           Canvas.Left="0"
           Canvas.Top = "0"/>
</Canvas>
```